# React Native Sending Email

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, amazon-ses

Goodday everyone, I am using **AWS SES** for sending a email, the storyline is, if the user forgot their password, the user will put their email address in the **TextInput** and it will send a code via email, (please refer to the image below)

***note:*** in my AWS SES, my account is already verified,

this is my sample code

```
  import React, {useState, createRef} from 'react';
  //i dont know if i am doing right here
  const submitForm = ({ event }) => {
    const payload = {
      url: '/user/forgotpassword',
      email: this.state.Email,
    };

    post(payload)
      .then(() => {
        // on success, clear any errors and set submitted state to true
        this.useState({ error: null, submitted: true });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // on error, update error state with the error message and set submitted to false
        this.setState({ error: error.message, submitted: false });
      });
  };

  <View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
     <Text style={formStyles.label1}>Email Address:</Text>
        <TextInput
  name="email"
  id="email"
  style={formStyles.inputStyle}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ Email: text })}
  placeholder="Enter Email Address"
  placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
  autoCapitalize="none"
  keyboardType="email-address"
  returnKeyType="next"
  underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
  blurOnSubmit={false}
/>
    </View>
    <Hoverable>
              {isHovered => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: isHovered ? '#FFFFFF':'#00ADEF',
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  color: '#FFFFFF',
                  borderColor: '#008ABE',
                  height: 37,
                  width: '90%',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  borderRadius: 8,
                  marginTop: 20,
                  marginLeft: 50,
                  marginRight: 50,
                  //
                }}
        onPress={() => submitForm()}
                activeOpacity={0.5}>
                <Text style={{
                  color: isHovered ? '#00ADEF':'#FFFFFF',
                  paddingVertical:5,
                  fontSize: 18,
                }}>Proceed to Password Reset</Text>
                
              </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
    </Hoverable>
```

node.js api

```
async function forgotpassword(req, res, next){
  var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "email-smtp.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "******************",
      pass: "******************"
    }
  });

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'support@ecomerce.com',
  to: 'testingfor573@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
}
```

this is the error

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `event` variable does not have a property by the name `target`..

Comment: what do you mean? i cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

For this create a state variable called `Email` and store its value.

On Pressing the submit button use this value to send mail..

Like this -

In your `constructor`

```
this.state = {
      ...
      Email: "",
      ...
    }
```

Your `` function should look like this -

```
const submitForm = ({ event }) => {
    const payload = {
      url: '/user/forgotpassword',
      email: this.state.Email,
    };

    post(payload)
      .then(() => {
        // on success, clear any errors and set submitted state to true
        this.setState({ error: null, submitted: true });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // on error, update error state with the error message and set submitted to false
        this.setState({ error: error.message, submitted: false });
      });
  };
```

Render code

```
<View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
        <Text style={formStyles.label1}>Email Address:</Text>
        <TextInput
          name="email"
          id="email"
          style={formStyles.inputStyle}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ Email: text })}
          placeholder="Enter Email Address"
          placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          returnKeyType="next"
          underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
        />
      </View>
      <Hoverable>
        {(isHovered) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              backgroundColor: isHovered ? '#FFFFFF' : '#00ADEF',
              borderWidth: 1,
              color: '#FFFFFF',
              borderColor: '#008ABE',
              height: 37,
              width: '90%',
              alignItems: 'center',
              borderRadius: 8,
              marginTop: 20,
              marginLeft: 50,
              marginRight: 50,
              //
            }}
            onPress={() => submitForm()}
            activeOpacity={0.5}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: isHovered ? '#00ADEF' : '#FFFFFF',
                paddingVertical: 5,
                fontSize: 18,
              }}>
              Proceed to Password Reset
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </Hoverable>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: Are you using `Class` or `Function` component?

Comment: Function @Kartikey

Comment: but in your `submitForm` function you used `this` which is used in class component...Add the whole code in question

Comment: oh, that code is from https://gist.github.com/amosuro/3fe2daac889d64f8723bdd600081eb8a#file-formcomponent-jsx

Comment: I am using class